# Linq query not knowing how to implement

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

First,

```cs
var query = from c in context.PreferredFeedUserCompaniesFollwers
            group c by c.CompanyID into company
            where company.Count() > 10
            select new { company.Key };
```

Second,

```cs
context.Companies.Where(query.contains(x=>x.Id)).tolist();
```

By using the first query it should return all the companyIDs that are repeated more than 10 times in the table Preferredusers, and by using the second query I should get all the details about the company with the companyIDs I got from the first query.

Neither are working. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
var query = (from c in context.PreferredFeedUserCompaniesFollwers
             group c by c.CompanyID into g
             where g.Count() > 10
             select c.CompanyID).Distinct();
```

If key is the id field, the above query should result in an `IQueryable<int>` and now your second query should work as well

Comment: companyid is the primary key there

Comment: then you should select the CompanyID so you can get the company id by primary key in the second query. I modified my answer

Comment: I am not getting c.count()>10 it is showing cannot resolve..And I have one doubt from our query I need to get the results of the duplicate companyid in table. how you are getting company id in our query

Comment: i was missing the group by so the count didn't work. how about now?

Comment: After adding group by c.companyid is not working..Cannot resolve symbol CompanyId. This is the problem I was facing from starting

Comment: Shouldn't the select-statement be:
`select g.Key`?

Answer (score 0):

First

```
var query = context.PreferredFeedUserCompaniesFollwers
    .Where(x => x.Count() > 10)
    .Select(x=> x.CompanyID)
    .Distinct();
```

Second

```
context.Companies.Where(query.contains(x => x.Id)).tolist();
```

I wrote it on the fly so hope it works

Edit : How About this? Not sure if the distinct is needed.

```
var query = context.PreferredFeedUserCompaniesFollwers
            .GroupBy(y => y.CompanyID)
            .Where(y => y.Count() > 10))
            .Select(x=> x.CompanyID)
            .Distinct();
```

Comment: Count is not working.It is showing the following. generate method for Count

Comment: Under Select Selected arguments cannot be used for usage and not getting x.companyid. I think here we need to change

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure. But the answer of middelpat looks correct to me. You are getting cannot resolve error in the first query. I just added company.CompanyID!=null condition.Can you try it?

```
    var query = (from id in     context.PreferredFeedUserCompaniesFollwers.Where(c=>c.CompanyID!=null).Select(c=>c.CompanyID)
    group id by id into g
    where g.Count() > 10 select id);
```

Comment: Hi, sorry for last query. I have edited the query. Can you try again?

Comment: Query Is fine But not getting the results from the database.I have many reocrds it is not getting null atleast

Answer (score 0):

First,

```
var query = context.PreferredFeedUserCompaniesFollwers
                   .GroupBy(c => c.CompanyId)
                   .Where(c => c.Count() > 10)
                   .Select(c => c.Key);
```

Second:

```
var result = context.Companies
                    .Where(x => query.Contains(x.Id))
                    .ToList();
```

But just from the top of my head. Could have a little error but this should do the trick.

Comment: If you want us to answer you question good, can you give use the layout of the PreferredFeedUserCompaniesFollwers and Companies,, the parts used in the query anyways